# find consecutive numbers using java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that compare between arrays and I got to the point where I have to check if there are any consecutive matches.

for example if i have 2 arrays:

`{3,4,2,5,6}` first array

`{4,8,9,2,5}` second array

in this example i have 3 consecutive matches which are 4,2,5.

in the first array we have 4,2,5 in order and they are in second array.

example 2:

{3,4,6,5,2}  first array

{4,8,9,2,5}  second array

in this one i have only 2 consecutive numbers which are 5 and 2.

5 and 2 are in order in the first array and they are in the second array.

```
public static boolean checkConsecutive(int[] firstArray,  int[] secondArray)
   {
      boolean consecutive = false;

      for(int i = 0; i < firstArray.length ; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++)
         {
            if (firstArray[i] == secondArray[j])
               consecutive = true;
            else 
               consecutive = false;
         }
      }
      return consecutive;
```

How can I know how many consecutive numbers I have?

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive matches? Total number of matches in the array?

Comment: Are you looking for set intersection? See `Set.retainAll()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: @user3080461 Just add one more counter to your code. int consecutive; and in the if loop write consecutive++; I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: _5 and 2 are in order in the first array and they are in the second array._, err what? and _in the first array we have 4,2,5 in order and they are in second array._, this doesn't make any sense to me. Can you provide some context into why you are trying to do what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

First your algorithm here does is comparing the last element of each arrays, returning false if they aren't equal and true if they match. Having the else condition here in your loop is making your algorithm wrong, because you're going to overwrite consecutive, sometimes changing it to false although it's already true. I just assume you don't want that.

Second think about it in an algorithmics way :

```
For(i) each of the first array's elements, 
    for(j) each element of the second array after the last match, until you find a match
        if you find a match, increase a counter, stop the second loop
```

You have to control the way you loop through the second loop, so that you count each element only once in the second array.

I don't know if I've been clear but that's hard to give clues whithout solving the problem for you.